# Deploy Angular 12 App to Salesforce using gulp-jsforce-deploy

Tags: angular, salesforce

I need to deploy angular 12 app in Salesforce using gulp-jsforce-deploy. If i get any reference blog/site, that would be very helpful for me.

Comment: Doing a quick online search on "angular salesforce deployment" yields a few viable results. Aren't any of those applicable to your use case?

Comment: @Aldin Bradaric - Based on that i have implemented the deployment script. it throws this error "content expected in separate file, not meta file for deploy"  
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68920251/error-salesforce-sandbox-angular-12-deployment-using-gulp-jsforce-deploy